# Excel: Count of reciprocal pairs in two columns

Tags: excel

I have two columns that each contain pairs of individuals.

```
Individual 1     Individual 2
A                B  
A                C
A                D 
B                A
C                A
C                D
```

How would I create a count of the number of times an individual has a reciprocal pair i.e. matched with the same partner but in the opposite order? For this example, the output should be:

```
A: 2
B: 1
C: 1
D: 0
```

Comment: A: 3? You only have 2 As in Column2

Comment: Sorry, yes that should be 2

Comment: This can be formulated graph theoretically. Let A,B,C, etc. be the nodes of a graph and draw an edge between two such nodes if it is what you are calling a "reciprocal edge". Then you are asking for the degree of each node in the graph. Trivial with VBA, not too bad with spreadsheet formulas if you don't mind a helper column. Probably possible without a helper column by an appropriate array formula. What sort of solution are you looking for? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is quite tricky but here are two suggestions

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A$2:A$7,B$2:B$7,B$2:B$7,A$2:A$7,A$2:A$7,C2))
```

or

```
=SUM(((A$2:A$7&B$2:B$7)=TRANSPOSE(B$2:B$7&A$2:A$7))*(A$2:A$7=C2))
```

The second one has to be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> and I'm assuming that the A's and B's are in A2:A7 and B2:B7 and you can get a list of the four individuals A, B, C and D in C2:C5.

[image]